# How to generate an array filled with a few different values?

Tags: javascript

I want to generate the following array:

```
[3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

there are 3 different values that should repeat `m`, `n`, and `k` times. What is the easiest way to do that?

If I do `Array(m + n + k).fill(...).fill(...).fill(...)` the start and end points in later `fill` calls look not very straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the arrays separately and then combine them into one final array

```
[
  ...Array(4).fill(3), 
  ...Array(2).fill(4), 
  ...Array(3).fill(5)
]
```

Comment: arrays are combined with `Array.from`?

Comment: @Poma sorry, what? `Array.from` converts an Array-like to array, what do you mean?

Comment: how do I flatten resulting array of arrays?

Comment: copy the code and paste it into the console and you will be surprised :)

Comment: oh I didn't notice the `...`

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of `values`, and an array of `repeat`. Iterate the `values` with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and return a new array filled with the values. Flatten by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const values = [3, 4, 5];
const repeat = [4, 2, 3];

const arr = [].concat(...values.map((v, i) => new Array(repeat[i]).fill(v)));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arrValues = [3,4,5];
var arrRepeats = [4,2,3];
var arr = [];

for(var i =0; i< arrRepeats.length;i++){
  arr.push(Array(arrRepeats[i]).fill(arrValues[i]));
}
console.log(arr)
```

> > Or
> >
> > ```js
> > var arrValues = [3,5,4];
> > var arrRepeats = [4,2,3];
> > let arr = [];
> > for(var i =0; i< arrRepeats.length; i++){
> >   for(var j=0; j<arrRepeats[i];j++){
> >     arr.push(arrValues[i]);
> >   }
> > }
> >
> > console.log(arr)
> > ```
> >
> > Or you can do that if you wanna generate arrays and combine them
> >
> > ```js
> > var arrValues = [3,5,4];
> >
> > var arrRepeats = [4,2,3];  // m, n, k
> > var mainArr = [];
> >
> > for(var i =0; i< arrRepeats.length; i++){
> >     var arr = [];
> >   for(var j =0; j < arrRepeats[i]; j++){
> >
> >     arr.push(j);
> >     arr.fill(arrValues[i]);
> >   } 
> >     mainArr.push(arr);
> >
> > }
> >
> >     console.log(mainArr)
> > ```